# how to set the root visual view in wpf

Tags: wpf, prism

what is the proper way of setting root visual using wpf. in silverlight examples that i have watched it like 
`ShellView view = this.Container.TryResolve<ShellView>();

            Application.Current.RootVisual = view;`

Seems root visual property does not exits in wpf, i tried following, but it does not load my shell view ( a usercontrol).

```
ShellView view = this.Container.TryResolve<ShellView>();            
Application.Current.MainWindow = Window.GetWindow(view);
```

what is the proper way of setting root visual in wpf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your question has the [prism](/questions/tagged/prism) tag, you can simply have a look at the StockTrader demo provided with Prism, which has the following lines in its bootstrapper:

```cs
protected override void InitializeShell()
{
    base.InitializeShell();

#if SILVERLIGHT
    Application.Current.RootVisual = (Shell)this.Shell;            
#else
    Application.Current.MainWindow = (Shell)this.Shell;
    Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
#endif
}
```

The place where you create the shell is the `CreateShell()` override, where `Shell` is of type `Window`:

```
protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
{
    return this.Container.TryResolve<Shell>();
}
```

You won't get any more "proper" than the way it's done in Prism's demo.